# php chown file in remote server ssh2

Tags: php, system-administration, openssh

I'm uploading one file from one server to other using ssh2_scp_send().

Everything works fine, the only problem is that I don't know how to change the owner and the group of the file after finishig the upload.

How can I preform some kind of chown in the ssh2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can do that with the [`ssh2_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-exec.php) function, which seems to allow running an arbitrary command on the server you're connected to.

That command could be the `chown` you're trying to execute.

The example from the doc says :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/usr/local/bin/php -i');
```

Replacing that "`/usr/local/bin/php -i`" with your "`chown user.group filename`" might do.